# Can we use use ThreadGroup inside a ThreadGroup

Tags: jmeter

Can we use use ThreadGroup inside a ThreadGroup?

I know that we can run it simultaneously but can we run a threadgroup inside a thread group is what i need to know.

Comment: Any feedback on my answer ?

Answer (score 1):

No you cannot by design.

@schtever answer is related to Java thread group, not jmeter thread group.

Why do you want to do that ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes.  One of the constructors for a ThreadGroup takes a parent ThreadGroup as a parameter.  See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ThreadGroup.html.

Comment: OP asks of this - https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/threads/ThreadGroup.html